# How to authenticate an application, instead of a user?

Tags: wcf, web-services, security, authorization

In the context of WCF/Web Services/WS-Trust federated security, what are the generally accepted ways to authenticate an application, rather than a user?  From what I gather, it seems like certificate authentication would be the way to go, IE generate a certificate specifically for the application.  Am I on the right track here?  Are there other alternatives to consider?

Comment: Could you clarify what you are trying to secure against?

Comment: I want my official client application to have special privileges to my web services, that normal api users would not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is solve the general Digital Rights Management problem, which is an unsolved problem at the moment.

There are a whole host of options for remote attestation that involve trying to hide secrets of some sort (traditional secret keys, or semi-secret behavioural characteristics).

Some simple examples that might deter casual users of your API from working around it:

- Include `&officialclient=yes` in the request
- Include `&appkey=<some big random key>` in the request
- Store a secret with the app and use a simple challenge/response: send a random `nonce` to the app and the app returns `HMAC(secret,nonce)`)

In general however the 'defenders advantage' is quite small - however much effort you put in to try and authenticate that the bit of software talking to you is in fact your software, it isn't going to take your attacker/user much more effort to emulate it.  (To break the third example I gave, you don't even need to reverse engineer the official client - the user can just hook up the official client to answer the challenges their own client receives.)

The more robust avenue you can pursue is licencing / legal options. A famous example would be Twitter, who prevent you from knocking up any old client through their [API licence terms and conditions](https://dev.twitter.com/terms/api-terms) - if you created your own (popular) client that pretended to the Twitter API to be the official Twitter client, the assumption is their lawyers would come a-knocking.

Comment: Fantastic answer... Regarding bullet 3, do you mean that if I use SHA, i just append the nonce to secret value before computing the hash?

Comment: HMAC is a keyed hash construction, it's very popular so the library that is offering you SHA-1 will most likely also offer HMAC-SHA-1. In my example the key input to HMAC is your application's secret key and the data to be mac'ed is the nonce.

Answer (score 3):

If the application is under your control (e.g. your server) then by all means use a certificate.
If this is an application under a user control (desktop) then there is no real way to authenticate the app in a strong way. Even if you use certificate a user can extract it and send messages outside the context of that application.
If this is not a critical secure system you could do something good enough like embedding the certificate inside the application resources. But remember once the application is physically on the user machine every secret inside it can sooner or later be revealed.