# In android, how to protect sensitive data or how to authenticate requests when developing a sdk

Tags: java, android, security, oauth, sdk

I'm developing a sdk for third-party apps to use, and I need to authenticate requests from the sdk on my server.

Now I solve this by hard-coding a private secret in sdk, then sdk use this secret to hash(md5) its request parameters as a sign which is sent to the server along with the other parameters. Then the server can check the sign, see if it's signed by a correct private secret, therefore, sdk I developed.

The question is:

- How can I protect this private secret from reverse engineering?
- Can I protect the private secret by encapsulating requests process in android NDK?
- Is there other better way to accomplish my root purpose: authenticate my sdk requests? How do the other sdks out there do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to prevent third parties from using their own software rather than your provided software, [it's not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18345282/515412).

You need to ensure that the security features are provided by your API, and you don't rely on controls present in your SDK. For example, don't expose sensitive data via your API that the SDK simply doesn't have the commands to call; use rate limiting at the server end not just at the SDK; etc. This is the same situation that arises with a website and client-side javascript: you can't trust the integrity of the client script at all, and you ensure that your website is secure anyway.

The normal way API usage is restricted is two-fold:

1. User authentication - each user who wants to use your service creates a user account and must establish an authenticated session to be able to use it.
2. API keys - each third party developer that wants to access your API is granted an API key, and it's up to them to protect their key. The API key is used to authenticate requests, for example by [appending a MAC over the request](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/HMACAuth.html).

Comment: Thanks. For clarification: I'm trying to prevent my api server from being attacked, the way of I'm doing it depends on a private key stored(which is insecure) in my sdk which will be used by other apps. So It's not user based, and all third-party apps just embed my sdk, all my sdk use the same private key for authentication, for now. Unfortunately I can't get a straight solution from your answer , I'll keep dig into the links your suggested, in the meantime, hope you can explain more, thanks again.