# Is using my app's key hash to verify that REST calls are coming from my app only secure enough?

Tags: android, security

I have a rest server and I want only my app to be able to communicate with my REST server. ie if someone puts the url in a browser they wouldn't be able to communicate with my server

At the moment i am thinking of adding my key hash as an extra parameter on my request calls and then storing the key

The hash is not stored on my app but is automatically retrieved using the following method.

```
public static void getHashes(Activity act) {
    PackageInfo info;
    try {
        info = act.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.my.package.myapp", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md;
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            String something = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
            //String something = new String(Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));
            Log.i("hash key", something);
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
        Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("exception", e.toString());
    }
}
```

I will have this method only called once for example at a certain time so that i can see it on the logcat and save it to my server after i compile to the production apk. this means it won't be outputed again for anyone else to see.

I will store this key on my server and my app will send this key everytime the a request is made. if the key is different then my server will not respond.

Is this method secure? can anyone see a flaw in it?

Comment: You're rolling your own security?  Yeah, I see a flaw with that.  No, it's not secure.  Why not use something like HMAC or OAuth2 on Android?

Comment: What is the loss when someone sniffs the Android traffic that makes it work, then uses wget or curl to fake it out to you? If it goes over the wire/air, it's not invisible. You'd do better if instead of a fixed value, you use a challenge-response based on a server selected nonce.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not secure.

An attacker can observe a single instance of this hash being sent in a request, and then include it in their own requests and your server won't be able to differentiate. The hash could, for example, be published on the web by the first person to obtain it.

However, this isn't just a problem with your approach: there are *no* known secure solutions to the general problem, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18345282/515412) for a slightly more comprehensive discussion (in the context of WCF rather than Android, but the argument is identical).

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to ask the server for the challenge first and then return the hashed value of the app key, that challenge, content of the message itself (other than signatures) and some random array of bytes that is known on both app and server side. If done this way, should be immune to the network sniffing, replay attacks and also attempts to use legitimate app as a message template generator (valid authentication, other content may be replaced). You may also authenticate the server side same way.

Unfortunately almost nothing can be done against reverse-engineering of your app after the .apk file is in the hands of the attacker. However Google and Amazon app stores offer some protection against getting the .apk for disassembling.